# Solution to use a javascript function with data coming from a database

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I was wondering if there is a solution to use a javascript function with PHP variables which i'm getting from a database. I know that PHP is a server language and javascript, a client language but i'm actually facing that problem. Maybe somebody can help me ?

I have points' GPS coordinates : "latitude" and "longitude" saved in my database and I get them by a function in PHP which returns me a PHP tab with th data in it.

Then I would like to insert the different points in a Google map with this javascript function :

```
function afficherPoint(latitude, longitude) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude); 
    var optionsMarqueur = { position: point, map: map, title: "test" }
    var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker(optionsMarqueur); 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example? What have you tried?

Comment: I have points' GPS coordinates : "latitude" and "longitude" saved in my database and i get them by a function in php which returns me a php tab with th data in it. Then i would like to insert the differents points on a google map with that javascript function : 'function afficherPoint(latitude, longitude)
    {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        var optionsMarqueur = {
                position: point,
                map: map,
                title: "test"
        }
        var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker(optionsMarqueur);     
    }'

Comment: that's better. I've added your extra details to your question to make the code more readable.

Comment: thanks a lot , I found a solution provides by Google Map Apis: 1. get the data in php 2. create an XML file with the data 3. use it to display the points on the google map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post the variables directly onto JavaScript (not the other way around), such as:

```
<?php
$name = "John";
?>
<script>alert("My name is <?php echo $name; ?>");</script>
```

Or if it's a dynamic thing, you can use AJAX.
If you are using jQuery, check this documentation: [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
You can call out to a PHP Script, and get new variables and do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

Just output the variable with PHP.

```
<?php
    $myVar = 'I am a variable';

    echo '<script>
            var stuff = "'.$myVar.'"
        </script>';
```

Then you can use the variable in javascript

Answer (score 0):

1. You could render your javascript using PHP.
2. You could have php define global JS variables, and you can then access them using javascript in a seperate file,
3. You could have your javascript asyncronously load the data from your webserver

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use php in javascript functions. A very basic example

`var aVar = "<?php echo $aVar; ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to this project :

[This tutorial from google](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3)

you can try

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3